Let $F_{n}$ denote the $n$th Fibonacci number, there exists $n_{0}$ such that $F_{n} \geq n^{2}, \forall n \geq n_{0}$
Note: This question was originally posted by user hd1 but he changed the question after I have written nearly all of the answer, so I posted it again for benefit, if I am not allowed to do this, tell me in comments to delete it.
This is the link of the question but he edited it to:Let $A$ be the set of all ten-digit numbers, where for each $a \in A$ the following holds
If $n \geq 12$, then $F_{n} \geq n^{2}$.
Proof by induction:
The statement is true for $n=12$, note that $F_{12}=144 \geq 12^{2}=144$, but we will choose base case to be $n=13$ which we will need in induction hypothesis.
Base case $n=13$ :
$F_{13}=233 \geq 13^{2}=169$.
Induction:
Assume $F_{n} \geq n^{2}, \forall n:13 \leq n \leq m $.
Want to prove it for $n=m+1.$
$F_{m+1}=F_{m}+F_{m-1}$
So, by induction hypothesis:
$F_{m}+F_{m-1} \geq m^{2}+(m-1)^2=2m^{2}-2m+1 \geq m^{2}+2m+1= (m+1)^{2}$.
Clarification:
$m^{2}+(m-1)^2=2m^{2}-2m+1=m^{2}+2m+1+(m^{2}-4m) \geq m^{2}+2m+1$, because $(m^{2}-4m) \geq 0$ for the range of our $m$, which is $ m \geq 13 $.

You don't have $F_{m-1}\ge(m-1)^2$, because $m-1$ might be $11$. So you also need the base case $n=13$ to take care of this.

@TonyK Thanks I will edit and correct the answer

The calculation $m^2 + (m-1)^2 = 2m^2 + 2m - 1$ is incorrect. This should be $m^2 +(m-1)^2 = 2m^2 - 2m + 1$.

@jMdA I will correct it, thanks for your remark.

Another way to see this is to just use Binet's Formula: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula

@hd1 It's $12$, but the proof works if we start from $13$, see the first comment, for $12$ the statement is just proved by calculating the value.

Actually, user hd1 originally posted the question about the ten-digit numbers, then replaced it with the question about Fibonacci numbers, then another user rolled it back to the question about ten-digit numbers.

We can use the lower bound of the Fibonacci number $F_n$, i.e. $\varphi^{n-2}\leq F_n\leq\varphi^{n-1},~\forall n\in\mathbb N_{>0}$, where $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\approx1.618033988749$ is the golden ratio.
We have to find $n_0$ such that $\varphi^{n-2}\geq n^2,~\forall n\geq n_0$.
$$\varphi^{n-2}\geq n^2\implies(n-2)\ln\varphi\geq2\ln n\implies\frac{n-2}{\ln n}\geq\frac{2}{\ln\varphi}=4.15617384247\ldots$$
Solving the transcendental equation $(x-2)\ln\varphi=2\ln x$ numerically gives $x=12.496\ldots,~0.738\ldots$. So, we have $n\geq12.496\ldots$ or $n\leq0.738\ldots$. But $n\in\mathbb N_{>0}$. So, the smallest natural number $n_0$ that satisfies the above inequality is $13$, i.e. $n_0=13$. According to WolframAlpha and Desmos, $\varphi^{n-2}\geq n^2\implies n\geq12.496\ldots,-0.542\ldots\leq n\leq0.738\ldots$. However, $F_n\geq\varphi^{n-2}$ and the equality $F_n=n^2$ holds for $n=12$, i.e. the perfect square $144=12^2$ is also a Fibonacci number. And, $F_{11}=89<121=11^2$. Hence, there exists $n_0=12$ such that $F_n\geq n^2,~\forall n\geq n_0=12$. $\blacksquare$

One can also find $n_0$ as follows.
$$F_n\geq n^2\implies F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}\geq (n-1)^2+(2n-1)\\\implies F_{n-2}-(2n-1)\geq(n-1)^2-F_{n-1}\geq0$$
So, we have to find the smallest $n=n_0$ such that the positive gap between $F_{n-2}$ and $(2n-1)$ becomes greater than or equal to that between $(n-1)^2$ and $F_{n-1}$. We have the sequence, $F_{n-2}=0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,\ldots$ and $(2n-1)=3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,\ldots$ for $n\geq2$. The first positive difference ($2$) is at $n=10$. But $9^2-F_9=81-34=47>2$. Again, at $n=11$, $F_9-21=34-21=13<10^2-55=45$. Now, at $n=12$, $F_{10}-23=55-23=32=11^2-89$. Hence, $F_n\geq n^2,~\forall n\geq n_0=12$.

Notice that there is an exact explicit solution to
$$\phi^{n+m}=n^k\quad \implies \quad n=-\frac{k }{\log (\phi )}\,\,W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (\phi)}{k}\,\,\phi ^{\frac{m}{k}}\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.
